# Match specific URL parameters that are not always together

Tags: javascript, php, regex

So, I have a little app that will do dynamic redirections with different URL parameters. The array on my PHP script establishes an **initial** order, like this:

```
$request = array(
    'extension' => 'rb',
    'type'      => 'blob',
    'size'      => '234900',
    'name'      => 'sdtt',
    'state'     => '1',
    'source'    => 'example.com',
)
```

Making the URL:

```
?extension=rb&type=blob&size=234900&name=sdtt&state=1&source=example.com
```

But the dynamic part could add or remove keys to the array. One of the keys that could be added is `expires` which is going to be at any position of the URL, because other parameters can be added too, meaning that I can't guarantee that it will be always after `source` or that will be the last URL parameter.

My goal is to target `type=anything` and `expires=anything` (for instance), save them to a variable and remove them from the URL (maybe with `pushState()` to avoid the page to be reloaded). Basically:

extension=rb&`type=blob&`size=234900&name=sdtt&state=1&source=example.com`&expires=1507755807`

My attempt was:

```
(type=[^&]+)(expires=[^&]+)
```

But that only gets me the `expires` parameter if exists, if it doesn't exists, it won't match anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add | (pipe) for 'or'

```
(type=[^&]+)|(expires=[^&]+)
```

Here is an example https://regex101.com/r/rXQijo/1

Comment: A pipe character... I can't believe it. I feel so dumb now haha thank you, @Himan.